# Addition of two field values in SSRS report expression

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I am trying to add two report fields in a placeholder expression in SSRS reports:

```
= SUM(Fields!TOTPRICE.Value) + SUM(Fields!TAX.Value)
```

But when I run the report i am getting error in the placeholder value.

Here is How I created the DataSource to the report

```
enter code here     <DataSources>
<DataSource Name="DummyDataSource">
  <ConnectionProperties>
    <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
    <ConnectString />
  </ConnectionProperties>
  <rd:DataSourceID>ef567ff-88fd-ef88f8f2b6b4</rd:DataSourceID>
</DataSource>
```

Here is how I created Dataset to the report:

```
 `enter code here`  <DataSets>
<DataSet Name="CStore_POReport">
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="IDOBJECTNAME">
      <DataField>IDOBJECTNAME</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="CDEACCOU">
      <DataField>CDEACCOU</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="NMEREQUE">
      <DataField>NMEREQUE</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="FLDTXTCONTACTPHONE">
      <DataField>FLDTXTCONTACTPHONE</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="NMECOMPANY">
      <DataField>NMECOMPANY</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="FLDTXTPOBOX">
      <DataField>FLDTXTPOBOX</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="NMESTREET">
      <DataField>NMESTREET</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="NMECITY">
      <DataField>NMECITY</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="NMESTATE">
      <DataField>NMESTATE</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="FLDTXTZIP">
      <DataField>FLDTXTZIP</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="NUMQTYORDER">
      <DataField>NUMQTYORDER</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="DSCITEM">
      <DataField>DSCITEM</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="CURUNITDOLLARS">
      <DataField>CURUNITDOLLARS</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="TXTUNITOFMEASURE">
      <DataField>TXTUNITOFMEASURE</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="TOTPRICE">
      <DataField>TOTPRICE</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="NUMTAXT">
      <DataField>NUMTAXT</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="TXTCOMMENTS">
      <DataField>TXTCOMMENTS</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="TAGTAX">
      <DataField>TAGTAX</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="NUMREQ">
      <DataField>NUMREQ</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="DTECREATED">
      <DataField>DTECREATED</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="TAX">
      <DataField>TAX</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="CRNCYID">
      <DataField>CRNCYID</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="CRNCY_SYMB_TXT">
      <DataField>CRNCY_SYMB_TXT</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="ITEM_CLS_CD">
      <DataField>ITEM_CLS_CD</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="ITEM_CD">
      <DataField>ITEM_CD</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
  </Fields>
  <Query>
    <DataSourceName>DummyDataSource</DataSourceName>
    <CommandText />
    <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
  </Query>
  <rd:DataSetInfo>
    <rd:DataSetName>CStore</rd:DataSetName>
    <rd:TableName>POReport</rd:TableName>
  </rd:DataSetInfo>
</DataSet>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYjdG.png

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: I am not getting any error while running the report but when i open the report the textbox with the expression field is just showing #Err ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got to know the solution for this ... i m surprised how many people had the same issue an yet there is not one post which can clearly explain the solution for this..

I've found two workarounds for this problem:

1) Changing Target Framework from 4.0 to 3.5 in the project settings

2) Adding the following line inside the web.config in the system.web section:

`<trust legacyCasModel="true" level="Full"/>`

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
= CStr(SUM(CInt(Fields!TOTPRICE.Value)) + SUM(CInt(Fields!TAX.Value)))
```

Ok i think your problem occurres due to which both of your fields' type are string, so before you can perform an add operation you need to convert them to integer

You need to convert the result to string in order to present it in the placeholder

I have created an example for you, First the QUERY

[image]

Next the report in edit mode
[image]

Has you can see i am presenting the TOPPRICE in the first column and the TAX in the second column and i wrote an expression for the third column

```
= CStr(CInt(Fields!TOTPRICE.Value) + CInt(SUM(Fields!TAX.Value)))
```

This is the results

[image]

Comment: Ok, i will need more information. you are using matrix layout or a table? are you making this expression outside a table (on the report body?) can you provide more information? can you show the query?

Comment: also if use any of the fields individually.. like if assign the expression SUM(Fields!TOTPRICE.Value) to a place holder i am getting the values in report but when i try to add both the report field where the value should appear is just showing #Error

Comment: I am using it in a tablix in the report body i am getting it from a data source which i created manually like in xml of the report and i am passing it the values from a query

Comment: Are you sure that one of them isn't null/noting?

Comment: yes actually i am using both of them individually in the same tablix just above this field ... now i just need to show the sum of both the other fields in this field

Comment: i didnt get ur second statement can you please explain it clearly also i have edited the qouestiona and uploaded the datasource and dataset structure

Comment: Can you upload a picture of your report in presentation mode?

Comment: hmm sorry i cant i work in a client remote server and i can not get the image transferred to my local desktop :(

Comment: Hi.. I forgot to mention yesterday .. the report is actually upgraded from reporting services 9.0 version to 10.0 .. it is actually working fine with 9.0 version but after converting i keep on getting this errors any idea of what might have went wrong...?

Comment: HI thanks agian.. but finally i got to know whtas the prob .. its nothing to do with conversion there is something wrong going on while i try to open it as pdf with the security settings.. so check out my answer we can do either of those to solve those.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you check these options if it works

1.Try with = SUM(VAL(Fields!TOTPRICE.Value)) + SUM(VAL(Fields!TAX.Value))

2.Make sure that your query is populating all the required columns

3.Make sure that your query has same column header name as you have mentioned in the report under  tag. For example if you have defined TAX but your query return the column header as tax/Tax, it might create issue because RDL backend is XML and case sensitive.

Comment: Yup I tried them all but no effect .. also I have fields where I have to show the individual value of both SUM(Fields!TOTPRICE.Value) and SUM(Fields!TAX.Value), they are both working fine individually and i'm getting the value but only when I try to add them together I am getting error field...